# Can I pass information to my Rakefile from my extconf.rb?

Tags: ruby, ruby-c-extension

I have a Ruby gem with a native extension that I am building with a [Rake compiler](https://github.com/rake-compiler/rake-compiler) ExtensionTask. I would like to take some action after the extension is built based on information calculated in `extconf.rb`. I tried writing the information to global variables in `extconf.rb` and then accessing those globals in the Rakefile, but they were empty. Is there any way to transfer that information to the Rakefile?

Answer (score 0):

Rake compiler calls `extconf.rb` in a subprocess ([here](https://github.com/rake-compiler/rake-compiler/blob/100d4241f27fbc9568846a2c1d7a63febeef4522/lib/rake/extensiontask.rb#L82C9-L82C26)), so you cannot access data from variables (constants for instance) from the `Rakefile` afterwards, at least not directly.

Basically, you want to communicate between two distinct processes. There are many tools for this, unix or Ruby. Here are some options:

1. write to a temporary file serialized data (I'd go for `JSON`), and read it afterward. Less involved option, but more than enough for most use cases
2. Use a FIFO special file with `File.mkfifo`, and read from it in another thread.
3. Use [`DRb`](https://devdocs.io/ruby%7E3/drb), you will still need to `Thread.fork`.

P.S: I see now it was asked so long ago, if you found a solution, I'd be glad to see it!